# Type Other than english language characters( Spanish) using sendKeys (Selenium, java)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

Storing an email template in a text file.
Need to type that email in the email functionality given by the website.
But Email template contains some Spanish characters which upon sendkeys represented by 
 in the text area of the email functionality where email body is supposed to be entered.

Need a solution to this.
Tried below code but it translated the whole page into Spanish and failed to recognize some xpaths.

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.addArguments("--lang=es");
```

Comment: Did you try to read your file as "UTF-8" with Reader class ?

Comment: Yes i tried that not working..

Comment: What happens if first you encode your .txt file with : http://snible.org/java2/uni2java.html  then send its content ?

Comment: Have to try...............